# How to take information thats entered into a entry box and save it in a text file

Tags: python, function, tkinter, tkinter-entry

So basically when i enter information into the two entry boxes, i want the data to go into a text file which can be accessed on other pages, but at the moment i need help to define the function i'm coding. If you do help, note that a new page (notepad preferably) needs to be added called "student". from #function onwards the code is abit messy and the code on the next line after def adduser(): is incorrect.

```
from tkinter import*


window = Tk()

window.title("Spelling Bee Opener")
window.geometry("600x400+500+250")
window.configure(bg="yellow")
label = Label(window,text = "Please Enter Your new Username and Password in the boxes below")
label.configure(bg='yellow')
label.place(x= 50, y=25)

Student=[]

#Username Entry

label = Label(window, text="Username")
label.configure(bg='Yellow')
label.place(x=50, y=70)
entry_box1=Entry(window,)
entry_box1.place(x=110,y=70)

#Password Entry

label = Label(window, text="Password")
label.configure(bg='Yellow')
label.place(x=50, y=100)
entry_box2=Entry(window,)
entry_box2.place(x=110, y=100)

# Function

def adduser():
    addstudent = open ("student.txt", "w")
    addstudent.write()

    window.destroy()


b = Button(window, borderwidth=2, text="Add New user", width=12, pady=5, command=adduser)
b.place(x=110,y=125)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Under your `addstudent.write()` you need to put something in the brackets to write in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.get()` to get that text in [entry](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm).

```
def adduser():
    addstudent = open ("student.txt", "w")
    addstudent.write("User ID: " + entry_box1.get())
    addstudent.write("\nUser Password: " + entry_box2.get())
    addstudent.close ()

    window.destroy()
```